# CSS for "Popup" not working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I found some code on the net to do the "popup" form in CSS using a div and the CSS opacity property.  It works great in IE and Chrome, but not FireFox.  In FireFox, nothing happens.  I've seen some issues with FireFox CSS on the boards, but nothing specific to what I'm looking at.  Any help on this issue would be great as I'm pretty new to CSS.  Thanks!

[Here][1] is the site where I got the code for reference.

CSS

```
        #blanket
    {
        background-color: #111;
        opacity: 0.65;
        filter: alpha(opacity=65);
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9001;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #popUpDiv
    {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        z-index: 9002;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<td align="left">
                    <div id="blanket" style="display: none;">
                    </div>
                    <div id="popUpDiv" style="display: none;">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">Close</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="color: Black;">
                                    Please describe the issue:
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtIssue" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="275" Height="200"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="cmdSend" runat="server" Text="Send" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">Click here to report an issue.</a>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblIssueStatus" runat="server" Text="" Style="color: Red;"></asp:Label>
                </td>
```

JS:

```
 function toggle(div_id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
    if ( el.style.display == 'none' ) { el.style.display = 'block';}
    else {el.style.display = 'none';}
}

    function blanket_size(popUpDivVar) {
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
    } else {
        viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if ((viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) && (viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.clientHeight)) {
        blanket_height = viewportheight;
    } else {
        if (document.body.parentNode.clientHeight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) {
            blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
        } else {
            blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
        }
    }
    var blanket = document.getElementById('blanket');
    blanket.style.height = blanket_height + 'px';
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
    popUpDiv_height=blanket_height/2-150;//150 is half popup's height
    popUpDiv.style.top = popUpDiv_height + 'px';
}

    function window_pos(popUpDivVar) {
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewportwidth = window.innerHeight;
    } else {
        viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if ((viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) && (viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.clientWidth)) {
        window_width = viewportwidth;
    } else {
        if (document.body.parentNode.clientWidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) {
            window_width = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
        } else {
            window_width = document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth;
        }
    }
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
    window_width=window_width/2-150;//150 is half popup's width
    popUpDiv.style.left = window_width + 'px';
}

    function popup(windowname) {
    blanket_size(windowname);
    window_pos(windowname);
    toggle('blanket');
    toggle(windowname);     
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see whether errors are reported in the Javascript error console, or in Firebug?

Comment: I tested and works for me in firefox 3.6.13

Comment: Not working in Chrome11b or FF4b11 here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/xdpTM/3/ `popup not defined`

Comment: Works fine for me in FF 3.0.8

Comment: Firefox lacks of innerText, outerHTML properties and siblings/childNodes in FF can be empty text nodes. I see none of these properties used, so yes, you need to look a error in firebug or at least in built-in error console (Ctrl+Shift+J).

Comment: Working in 3.6.13 for me too.

Comment: @Myles What happens for you if you choose "no wrap (head)" rather than onLoad() under "Choose Framework"?

Comment: Hey all, 
I've tried to debug and the first thing I get is "popup is not defined" so that function I'm calling isn't even getting called for some reason.  I have the js file referenced in my header so I don't know why FireFox wouldn't get it.  I'm using FF 3.6.13

<script type="text/jscript" src="../js/csspopup.js"></script>

Comment: Figured it out.  Very stupid, has the type tag in the header set to jscript.  Stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my script type tag was jscript, my dumb mistake.  Thanks for the help everyone!